# Вопрос о работе с библиотекой retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Я хочу реализовать получение информации с JSON'a таким образом:

Сначала получаю ссылку на данный json с другого json'a и после этого загружаю тот json по ссылке.
Но я не знаю как можно сделать по получаемой ссылке, так как там можно только вписать в @GET сразу ссылку.

т.е

1. Загружаем json и извлекаем ссылку на другой json
2. по этой ссылке загружаем json

Comment: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Url.html

Comment: это не то. если бы мой вопрос был в документации, я бы сюда не писал..

Comment: все, кажется дошло как реализовать это

Comment: То, в документации есть ответы может и не на все, но многие вопросы :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/58276101/5479247